# Auto-correlation with weekly data

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, timeserieschart

I am a new user to R and try to calculate **weekly** auto correlation between 2 financial time series with ccf function.

Here is my code:

```
SPX_ImpliedVola_ts<-ts(SPX_ImpliedVola$x, start=c(2005), end=c(2014), freq=52)
SPX_GSV_ts<-ts(SPX_GSV$x, start=c(2005), end=c(2014), freq=52)
plot(ccf(SPX_ImpliedVola_ts,SPX_GSV_ts, type= "correlation"))
```

The results of ccf function make sense, but the labelling of x-axis is wrong. My lags should be weeks. The plot function uses years instead and therefore on lag is =1/52. I do not have enough reputation points to post the plot

Is there an easy way to format the x axis, so that 1 lag = 1 week?

Here is my data for the year 2013:

SPX_GSV_ts

```
structure(c(-0.172545978, -0.085914629, -0.051152522, -0.191885526, 
0.10720997, 0.120573931, 0.123062732, -0.073231914, 0.122783425, 
-0.073231914, -0.091330136, -0.108595771, -0.149988456, -0.077412223, 
0.017728767, -0.057991947, -0.04522754, 0.098925304, 0.019744058, 
-0.042403849, 0.097955247, 0.060480747, -0.096910013, 0.04275198, 
-0.111150452, -0.123384909, 0.020203386, 0.02540458, 0.046743404, 
0.046743404, 0.096910013, -0.029289376, -0.020203386, 0.019305155, 
0.124938737, 0.071494417, 0.080655932, 0.032184683, -0.072195125, 
0.08058446, 0.109144469, -0.116215168, -0.003792989, -0.011685758, 
0.033281387, -0.011685758, 0.044203662, -0.137383556, -0.023912157, 
0.023065304, 0.037141808, -0.128799157, -0.036045104), .Tsp = c(2013, 
2014, 52), class = "ts")
```

SPX_ImpliedVola_ts:

```
structure(c(0.1551244, 0.1764986, 0.169477, 0.1509566, 0.14180975, 
0.1455916, 0.1320918, 0.150884, 0.1519094, 0.1670364, 0.1769658, 
0.1491722, 0.14883, 0.13545475, 0.134158, 0.1292596, 0.13465, 
0.14380075, 0.136281, 0.1350982, 0.1384192, 0.1467728, 0.161534, 
0.14764, 0.1332734, 0.1353106, 0.126313, 0.1268324, 0.1200864, 
0.1242202, 0.127857, 0.1382412, 0.1319932, 0.1441192, 0.1316964, 
0.1217246, 0.1262966, 0.11574475, 0.1166192, 0.1231602, 0.119756, 
0.10622025, 0.1133376, 0.1245488, 0.1124368, 0.11566475, 0.1196388, 
0.1003482, 0.0994486, 0.0972232, 0.10798775, 0.1115012, 0.1148464
), .Tsp = c(2013, 2014, 52), class = "ts")
```

Comment: Would you please provide a reproducible example. You can use `dput` for subset of your data.

Comment: Hi @Ahmed, thank you for a quick reply. I have just uploaded the data using dput function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `ccf` does not plot the number of lags properly for `ts` class. You need to change the class of your data to `data.frame` to get the proper number of lags on the x-axis. You can use the following code:

```
ccf.results<-ccf(data.frame(SPX_ImpliedVola_ts),data.frame(SPX_GSV_ts), type= "correlation", ylab="Auto-correlation", main="Weekely Auto-corelations")
```

You can remove `type= "correlation"` and you will still get the same results as the default `type` for `ccf` is `correlation`

Also the plot you have from last code does not give access to the specific value of each lag. To check the value of each lag you need to assign the `ccf` results variable name and thin print it as follow:

```
ccf.results<-ccf(data.frame(SPX_ImpliedVola_ts),data.frame(SPX_GSV_ts), type= "correlation")
print(ccf.results)
```

You will get:

```
Autocorrelations of series ‘X’, by lag

   -14    -13    -12    -11    -10     -9     -8     -7     -6     -5     -4     -3     -2     -1 
-0.010  0.076  0.011 -0.017 -0.031 -0.057 -0.037  0.059  0.067  0.033  0.105  0.000 -0.242 -0.181 
     0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11     12     13 
-0.189 -0.157 -0.079  0.041  0.080 -0.015 -0.098 -0.302 -0.303 -0.355 -0.323 -0.264 -0.222 -0.116 
    14 
-0.121
```

Note that `0` in the results above means the `correlation` without any lags.

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for the explanations! The code you have provided works perfect :) Sadly, I do not have enough reputation points to "vote up" your answer. But once I have it, I will vote up your answer!